# Highcharts Gauge: Labels radius styling

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

In my browser (Firefox 12), this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/QeJGx/) of a Highcharts Chart looks not correct. The labels are not styled in the same radius as the background radius is.

Is there any option in Highcharts to fix this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are options on the label that will fix this.  If you format the label according to the below code the label should arc properly around the gauge.

```
labels: {
    step: 2,
        rotation: 'auto',
        align: 'center',
        distance: 15,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
},
```

I updated your [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QeJGx/50/) to demonstrate.  You were missing the **x** and **y** position offsets.